# Is there a way to update zip files automatically?

Tags: command-line, script, compression, zip

When updating a **zip** file with option `-u` it will update/freshen any file that has changed, add any file that has been added BUT it will not delete any file that is not in the source tree any more.

I suppose this is intentional to make it possible to start from a tree that only contains added/changed files.

But is there still one option to enable this with some trick that will save me time, since I'm working with very big zip files, compared to new zip generation from scratch?

Thanks in advance,

tent:wq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the option I was looking for in the man page finally:

`-FS` (or `--filesync`)!

So for instance:

```
zip -FS9ryo archive.zip directory_to_compress/*
```

will completely sync `-FS` what is in folder "directory_to_compress" with the archive.zip file (no matter if you created, deleted or updated files in that dir); it will compress with maximum compression level `-9`; it will recurse into sub-directories `-r`; store symlinks as is and not as referenced file and set the date of the zip archive to the latest file in dir `-o`.

Comment: Also found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17123365/sync-zip-file-with-folder/17123399#17123399

Comment: Tent, would you please give some examples in your answer?

Comment: I added an example, from my specific use-case but basically just use option `-FS` on top of your other usual options that you use to compress if you want ZIP to sync folder and archive. Only if you already use either `-f` or `-u` you need to replace `-FS` with them.

Comment: I was a little confused with the several options listed in this answer. Many of these are not needed. To summarize the above, the command is `zip archive_to_update -FS -r dir_used_before`. Check the link in the first of tent's comments